# Using CMake with CTest and CDash

Tags: c++, cmake, cdash

I am going to use CDash  with CMake/CTest on my C++ project.

In order to enable CDash and customize settings, like 
**"MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE"**, **"DART_TESTING_TIMEOUT"**, I added the following lines in the root ***CMakeLists.txt***

```
set(MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/valgrind.supp")
set(DART_TESTING_TIMEOUT "120")
include(CTest)
```

However, the generated ***"DartConfiguration.tcl"*** does not contain my settings at all
( MemoryCheckSuppressionFile is empty and TimeOut is still the default value )

**I found that, for example, if I pass -DDART_TESTING_TIMEOUT=STRING:120 , it works , but it fails if specifying them in the CMakeLists.txt.**

Thank you in advance :)

> DartConfiguration.tcl

```
# Dynamic analisys and coverage
PurifyCommand:
ValgrindCommand:
ValgrindCommandOptions:
MemoryCheckCommand: /usr/bin/valgrind
MemoryCheckCommandOptions:
MemoryCheckSuppressionFile:
CoverageCommand: /usr/bin/gcov

# Testing options
# TimeOut is the amount of time in seconds to wait for processes
# to complete during testing.  After TimeOut seconds, the
# process will be summaily terminated.
# Currently set to 25 -9.0.0.71596-0inutes
TimeOut: 1500
```

Answer (score 3):

There are three possible solutions:

1. You create cache variables. This also creates a GUI entry for the variable, which is not always what you want for automatic testing: `SET(DART_TESTING_TIMEOUT "120" CACHE STRING "")`
2. You specify your options with a simple "set" command, but in a file called DartConfig.cmake instead of the main CMakeLists.txt . This file gets parsed to create the DartConfiguration.tcl
3. You use CTest scripting to set up your dartclient: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Scripting_Of_CTest